# How to disable vs code from expanding folder when single clicked on its name in built-in explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to expand folder only when clicked on arrow. How could I accomplish this? I can disable files from opening on single click, setting `workbench.list.openMode` to `double click`. I need the same setting for expanding on arrow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"workbench.tree.expandMode": "doubleClick"